# mpm configuration for httpd

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, worker

I run a website with 5 httpd servers(Centos 7) in EC2, type is m3.2xlarge.
The servers are configured with load balancer.
Gradually the server memory keeps going higher in all the instances.

For example:

Memory usage in few seconds after restarting the httpd service:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-1-77 ~]$ while  sleep 1; do free -m; done
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          29741        2700       26732          36         307       26728
Swap:             0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          29741        2781       26651          36         307       26647
Swap:             0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          29741        2820       26613          36         307       26609
Swap:             0           0           0
[centos@ip-10-0-1-77 ~]$ 
.
.
.
```

This is what i see after an hour:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-1-77 ~]$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          29741       29092         363          41         284         346
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Like above it goes and consumes all the memory(30GB) within an hour.

To avoid this I started using worker mpm configuration.

The following configuration is what I have added at the bottom of /etc/httpd/httpd.conf.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
MaxRequestWorkers 2500
MaxSpareThreads 250
MinSpareThreads 75
ServerLimit 100
StartServers 3
ThreadsPerChild 25
</IfModule>
```

Can Someone help and suggest me the right configuration to utilize the RAM memory properly in all the instances?

Answer (score 0):

A standard Apache process takes up about 12 MB of RAM. If you have 30 GB reserved for Apache you will never reach that with a serverlimit of 100 (=100*12MB=1200MB=1,2GB). So I assume that Apache isn't taking up all that memory.

Is there an application that is involved or a DB? Those can take up larger amounts of RAM.

For your `servertuning.conf` (or httpd.conf since you put it there):

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    #max amount of requests one worker handles before it's forced to close, 2,5k seems almost a little low
    MaxRequestsperChild 2500

    #maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
    #250 seems quite high, but really depends on the traffic you are experiencing, we normally don't use more than 50-75
    MaxSpareThreads 250

    #minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
    #really high, only useful if you often experience higher bursts of traffic
    #otherwise you should be fine with 15-30, maybe 50 if you experience higher fluctuation -> bigger bursts of requests
    MinSpareThreads 75

    #upper limit on the configurable number of threads per child process
    #you have to increase this if you want more than 64 ThreadsPerChild
    ThreadLimit 64

    #maximum number of simultaneous client connections
    #that is really low! --> increase that, definitely! We run on 1000, so about 12GB max
    MaxClients 100

    #initial number of server processes to start
    #3 is really low, if you expected your server to be flodded with requests the second you start it
    #maybe turn it up a little to around 20 or even 50 if you receive lots of traffic right after a restart
    StartServers 3

    #number of worker threads created by each child proces
    #25 threads per worker is not tooo much, but at some point the administration of xx threads gets more expensive than creating new ones
    #would suggest to leave it at 25 or turn it up to around 40
    ThreadsPerChild 25
</IfModule>
```

Notice that I changed `ServerLimit` to `MaxClients` and `MaxRequestWorkers` to `MaxRequestsPerChild`, because as far as I know those are the terms used in `mpm-worker`.

Additionally you can change following variables:

```
#KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
#one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#if it's on, leave it there
KeepAlive On

#MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
#during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
#We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#default=100, but you can turn that up if your sites contain a lot of item (img, css, ...)
#we are using about 20*<average object-count per site> = 600
MaxKeepAliveRequests 600

#KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
#same client on the same connection.
#would recommend to decrease that, otherwise you could become a victim of slow-dos attacks
#default is 15, we are running just fine on 5
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

To further prevent slow-dos or piling up of open sessions, you can use `mod_reqtimeout`:

```
<IfModule mod_reqtimeout.c>
  # allow 10s timeout for the headers and allow 1s more until 20s upon receipt of 1000 bytes.
  # almost the same with the body, except that it is tricky to
  # limit the request timeout within the body at all - it may take time to generate the body.
  # below are the default values
  #RequestReadTimeout header=10-20,MinRate=1000 body=20,MinRate=1000
  # and this is how I'd set them with today's internet speed
  # deduct the according numbers from explanation above...
  RequestReadTimeout header=2-5,MinRate=100000 body=5-10,MinRate=1000000
</IfModule>
```

---

If that's not enough to help your RAM-issues (if they are really caused by Apache), use the tools of your server's OS accordingly to find out what is taking up all the RAM --> [TOOLS](http://www.brendangregg.com/Perf/linux_perf_tools_full.png)

Comment: Thanks for clear and detailed explanation.
I just came back to work. Let me try your solution and will get back to you asap.
Thanks Fishy.